# Check opaque behavior in Acceleo

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

I need to Check if an Element is an opaque behavior.
How I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If an "Opaque Behavior" is a type, you can use plain OCL :

```
element.oclIsKindOf(OpaqueBehavior)
```